# Why standard container iterators don't overload `->*`?

Tags: c++, iterator, operator-overloading, language-lawyer

Apparently `->*` doesn't work automagically if you overload `->`, and has to be overloaded manually.

Why iterators for standard containers don't overload `->*` in addition to `->`, forcing usage of `(*iter).*mem_ptr` instead of `iter->*mem_ptr`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct S
{
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<S> vec = {{42}};
    auto mem_ptr = &S::x;

    std::cout << (*vec.begin()).*mem_ptr << '\n'; // This line compiles.

    std::cout << vec.begin()->*mem_ptr << '\n'; // This line doesn't compile.
}
```

Comment: I suspect because of: _"If a user-defined `operator->` is provided, the `operator->` is called again on the value that it returns, recursively, until an `operator->` is reached that returns a plain pointer. After that, built-in semantics are applied to that pointer."_ http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access  ie there are significant differences.

Comment: Do standard container iterators overload `operator->`? A std:.vector should simply use T* as iterator.

Comment: Overloading the pointer to member access operator is different from the other overloads, since its return type  depends on the type of the argument and therefore has to be a template to support members of all types. Perhaps that is part of the reason...

Comment: @manni66 yes, standard container iterators (which are all input iterators) do overload `operator->`. There are other container besides `std::vector` that cannot simply use a pointer. And there is no requirement for `std::vector::iterator` to be a pointer either.

Comment: @manni66 see `std::vector<bool>` (proxy access) although they now wish they had not.

Comment: @RichardCritten: The problem with `std::vector<bool>` is not the implementation, it's the name.  Call it `std::packedbitvector`, with exactly the same guts, proxies and all, and voila no more problems.  But as an overload of `std::vector`, it breaks every other `template <class T>` function and type that tries to use `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: @BenVoigt you said the same as I meant to with better words.

Comment: @RichardCritten: Ok, from your comment it wasn't clear whether you meant "they wish they had not made proxy accessors" or "they wish they hadn't done that in `vector<bool>`"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is [fundamentally unanswerable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/2069064).

Comment: @Barry I'm seeing at least two possible answers: "It is an oversight" or "It is not possible (or not efficient) because of X".

Comment: I'm not asking why a certain design decision was made, but rather whether I stumbled upon a defect or overlooking something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the caveat that these questions aren't typically answerable, here are a few reasons why `operator->*()` may not be overloaded. Although it's possible the real answer is that nobody thought of it. And if this, to you, is an important missing language feature, you could always [submit a proposal](https://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-proposal).

---

For starters, `ptr->*pmd` just isn't a very commonly used expression in general. So the fact that you cannot write `it->*pmd` isn't something that most people miss, especially when `(*it).*pmd` accomplishes exactly the same goal at the cost of just 2 extra characters. The potential upside here seems fairly small. Still, iterators should be consistent with pointers, so it would make sense. But...

Pointers to members aren't just pointers to member data, we can also have pointers to member functions and can write `(ptr->*pmf)()` today, where `ptr->*pmf` by itself is ill-formed. You can't get those semantics at all with `operator->*` - to get the call operation to work, `ptr->*pmf` would have to basically return a lambda. So now, this actually becomes fairly complicated - unless you want to just support `ptr->*pmd`. With any approach, you're inconsistent with pointers.

For input iterators, you don't want to support `operator->*()` at all since it would yield an immediately dangling reference.

To me, personally, the cost (figuring out how to specify these operators, for which iterators, and what to do about pointers to member functions) doesn't really seem worth the benefit (saving 2 characters in an expression that's rarely written).