# How to execute member-function-pointer with a smart pointer object?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, pointer-to-member

I am trying to execute a `member-function` of a class with a smart pointer instance. The address of this function is passed by value, which I want to call though a smart pointer instance of the respective class.

I already tried this:

```
(registerList.*setRegister)();
```

But it errors out:

```
no match for ‘operator->*
```

`Register` class member function:

```
uint16_t Registers::getSP()
{
    return this->sp;
}
```

The code snippet:

```
std::unique_ptr<Registers> registerList;

SetRegisteropcodeLdWordRegister(&Registers::getSP)

void opcodeLdWordRegister(uint16_t (*Registers::setRegister)()) 
{
        (registerList.*setRegister)();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your shown code and the error message does not match. For the given code [you should be getting (from clang) following error message](https://godbolt.org/z/wyqMqm)

```
error: left hand operand to .* must be a class compatible with the right hand operand, but is 'std::unique_ptr<Registers>'    
   (registerList.*setRegister)();
            ^
```

This can be solved by dereferencing the pointer(*like in @Caleth's answer*):

```
((*registerList).*setRegister)();
```

---

Now the error message that was shown in the question: `no match for ‘operator->*` should be coming when you would have tried the following syntax.([Minimal reproducible code](https://godbolt.org/z/DSgMBs))

```
(registerList->*setRegister)();
```

This is because smart pointers do not have the [pointer-to-member access operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Standard_library) defined in the standard. Therefore, you need to go for dereferencing the smart pointer via `operator*` or by member function [`std::unique_ptr::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get), and call the member function.

Using the member `std::unique_ptr::get` the correct syntax would be **([See the live demo online](https://godbolt.org/z/zrvBRV))**

```
(registerList.get()->*setRegister)()
```

---

That being said, if you have access to [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) use unified version of function invoker [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) to invoke the member function with the respective instance, by which you can forget about the (maybe)complicated syntax for `operator->*`.

Your code has a couple of issues too:

- The member function pointer type in your `opcodeLdWordRegister` is
  wrong.It should have been

  ```cpp
  return_type(Class_name::* variable_name)(/*parameters_types, if any*/)
  ```

  Following is the fixed version.

  ```cpp
  #include <functional>  // std::invoke

  void opcodeLdWordRegister(uint16_t(Registers:: * setRegister)())
  //                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ >>> correct syntax
  {   
      std::invoke(setRegister, registerList);
      //          ^^^^^^^^^^^                 member function
      //                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^   instance
   }
  ```
- Secondly, dereferencing of the uninitialised `registerList` pointer
  will cause UB.

Following is the demonstrative minimal complete example for the case: **([See the live demo online](https://godbolt.org/z/PYCAwY))**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>  // std::invoke
#include <memory>      // std::unique_ptr

class Registers
{
   uint16_t sp{2};        // member initialized with 2
public:
   uint16_t getSP() const // function can be marked const as it does not alter the member
   {
      return this->sp;
   }
};

auto registerList = std::make_unique<Registers>(); // initialized the pointer with default object

void opcodeLdWordRegister(uint16_t(Registers::*setRegister)() const)
//                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  correct syntax
{
   std::cout << std::invoke(setRegister, registerList);
}

int main()
{
   opcodeLdWordRegister(&Registers::getSP);
   return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
2
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `*registerList`?

Comment: @Evg I think, it is not needed: https://wandbox.org/permlink/jz9jQQfdJj6R0fjO

Comment: I see. `std::invoke` will starrify for us.

Comment: The point of `std::invoke` is to unify call syntax. In this case it's "If `t1` does not satisfy the previous items, then `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` is equivalent to `((*t1).*f)(t2, ..., tN)`."

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke), you can still do what it would do, which is to dereference the (unique) pointer in the call site.

```
((*registerList).*setRegister)();
```

Comment: The smart pointer must implement `operator->*` for the second syntax to be usable. The standard library types don't do that.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, is there a reason why?

Comment: @Evg because *everyone* forgets `->*` is a thing?

Comment: @Evg - If I had to hazard a guess I'd say it's because handling both member function and member data in C++11 (when the smart pointers were added) was kinda difficult. The cost/benefit ratio of adding this niche feature wasn't great at the time. In C++17 it's much simpler, but I don't think this is on anyone's mind, really.

Comment: @Evg Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48626039/why-standard-container-iterators-dont-overload